# Copy and paste UNIX executables to $PATH does not work?

Tags: mac, command-line, bash

Why is it when I copied the C compiler tools from the Xcode application folder to usr/bin (which is one of the $PATH for Mac OS X), Terminal doesn't seem to be able to see it? Running a find command on it yields no results: "./gcc: No such file or directory". Executing the command that I know is in usr/bin according to Finder brings the error: "./gcc: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be running `./gcc`. In the *nix world, `./` means "the current directory". So, when you run `./gcc` you are telling the OS to look for an executable called `gcc` which is in the directory you happen to be in. Unless you run the command from `/usr/bin`, no such executable will be found and you will get an error.

Since you have placed `gcc` in a directory that is in your path, you don't need to give a full path to access it, just the name. So instead of `./gcc` run `gcc` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of things to check out:

1. After moving the binaries, you might have to tell your terminal to re-scan the PATH.  Run the command 'rehash' to do that.
2. You should update your path to point to the tools, not move the tools to point to the path.  Update the path by doing this:

   export PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/tools/dir" ; rehash

Comment: +1 for the second point. Adding to the path is the right way (tm).

Answer (score 1):

If you put the executable in /usr/bin ,you can access it by , just using 'gcc' No need for './'. Also the permission of newly added command should be 755.

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/command_name
```

Comment: Keep in mind though it's not wise to give all programs you move 755 permissions.